# Django reverse relationship (with annotate and filtering)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to get players with less than 5 records in the "MatchSup" table for specific matches

Player.objects.filter('age="25"',matchsup__match__in='matchlist').annotate(numviews=Count('matchsup__player__lt=5',)) like this (that's wrong i know)

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    age=  ...


class MatchSup(models.Model):
    player= models.ForeignKey(Player, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    match = models.ForeignKey('Match', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: There is no field `age` in your `Player` model though?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I took it off as I was writing here so that it wouldn't create a crowd (i edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`annotate` the count on the `Player` model and filter on the count:

```py
from django.db.models import Count


Player.objects.filter(
    age=25,
    matchsup__match__in=matchlist
).annotate(
    match_count=Count('matchsup')
).filter(match_count__lt=5)
```